# D3 JS - Group Containing a SVG Rectangle Won't Translate Smoothly on Drag

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I created a rectangle on the SVG container by using D3 drag events.

I tried to implement moving the rectangle by applying 2D transfoms (using translate(x,y)) on the parent  element of the drawn rectangle.

After drawing the rectangle I get the bounding box values of the  container which the rectangle is contained in. Then I set the (x,y) bounding box coordinates to (0,0) thereby shifting the rectangle to the upper right corner of the viewport. Then I translate it back to the original position. Then again apply the translation by updating it with the mouse event coordinates on dragging the rectangle.

```
     d3.select('#rectangle').on('click', function(){ new Rectangle(); } );

function Rectangle(){

    var rectData = []; //holds the diagonal point 1 and 2 coordinates of the rectangle
    var rectContainer; // g element
    var shape = {}; //will hold the rectangle's d3 selections
    var start; //starting point
    var edge; //ending point
    var gData = {}; //holds translate values for g element

//    console.log(this);

    var rectangleDrag =  svgCanvas.call(d3.drag().on("start", initialPlod)
        .on('drag', secondaryPlod)
        .on('end', onStopDraw));

    //start rendering on drag start
    function initialPlod(){
        start = d3.mouse(this);
//      console.log(start);
        rectData = [{x:start[0], y:start[1]}, {x:start[0], y:start[1]}];
        rectContainer = svgCanvas.append("g");
        shape.rectEl = rectContainer.append('rect').attr('class', 'rectangle');
        renderRectangle();
    }

    //when continuing to drag from point 2
    function secondaryPlod(){
        edge = d3.mouse(this);
        rectData[1] = {x: edge[0], y: edge[1]};
        renderRectangle();
    }

    //on stop drawing bind a drag event
    function onStopDraw(){

        svgCanvas.call(d3.drag().on("start", null)
            .on('drag', null)
            .on('end', null));

        var bbox = shape.rectEl._groups[0][0].getBBox();
        console.log(this);
        console.log(bbox);

        //temporary variables that hold original position
        var rectCords = {
            x: bbox.x,
            y: bbox.y
        };

        //setting boundingbox to 0,0 coordinates
        bbox.x = 0;
        bbox.y = 0;

//      console.log(bbox);

        shape.rectEl.attr("x", bbox.x).attr("y", bbox.y);

        gData.x = rectCords.x;
        gData.y = rectCords.y;

        rectContainer.attr("transform", "translate(" + gData.x + "," + gData.y + ")");

        shape.rectEl.call(d3.drag().on("drag", dragRect));
    }

    //grab and drag rectangle
    function dragRect() {
        var move = d3.event;
        rectContainer.attr("transform", "translate(" + (gData.x += move.dx)  + "," + (gData.y += move.dy) + ")");
    }

    /**
     *
     * Method takes the x,y coordinates from rectData object array
     * which contains coordinates of point1 and point2
     * and calculates the the height and width
     *
     */
    function renderRectangle(){
        //rectangle attributes
        var xCoord = rectData[1].x - rectData[0].x > 0 ? rectData[0].x :  rectData[1].x;
        var yCoord = rectData[1].y - rectData[0].y > 0 ? rectData[0].y :  rectData[1].y;
        var width = Math.abs(rectData[1].x - rectData[0].x);
        var height = Math.abs(rectData[1].y - rectData[0].y);

        //render rectangle
        shape.rectEl.attr("x",xCoord)
            .attr("y", yCoord)
            .attr("width",width)
            .attr("height",height);
    }

}
```

The rectangle translates but it's erratic. However if I apply the same technique to a SVG circle it translates just fine on mouse drag. Both shapes can be drawn on the same viewport.

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yesin/ysqLd2c3/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the cause of the issue.

I had bound the drag event to the rectangle element inside the g element which seems to have caused the erratic translating when dragging the rectangle. Since I'm translating the g element when dragging the rectangle it may have caused the issue.

I bound the drag event to the rectangle container (g element) element and it translates smoothly on drag now.

```
    //on stop drawing bind a drag event
    function onStopDraw(){

        svgCanvas.call(d3.drag().on("start", null)
            .on('drag', null)
            .on('end', null));

        var bbox = shape.rectEl._groups[0][0].getBBox();
        console.log(this);
        console.log(bbox);

        //temporary variables that hold original position
        var rectCords = {
            x: bbox.x,
            y: bbox.y
        };

        //setting boundingbox to 0,0 coordinates
        bbox.x = 0;
        bbox.y = 0;

//      console.log(bbox);

        shape.rectEl.attr("x", bbox.x).attr("y", bbox.y);

        gData.x = rectCords.x;
        gData.y = rectCords.y;

        rectContainer.attr("transform", "translate(" + gData.x + "," + gData.y + ")");

//bound the drag event to the entire g element of the rectangle
            rectContainer.call(d3.drag().on("drag", dragRect));
        }
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yesin/ze2ktakv/)